# Error code 4 when uplading multiple files via Ajax Php

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple files via Php and ajax , and when doing so I recieve error code 4 .

My form looks like that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form#postForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData($form[0]); // note [0] here
        $.ajax({
            url: "postHandler",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(response.message);
                if (response.success) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```

```
<form id="postForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file-upload" name="images[]" type="file"/>

    <input id="file-upload" name="images[]" type="file"/>

    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file[]"/>

    <input id="file-upload" name="file[]" type="file"/>

    <input id="file-upload" name="file[]" type="file"/>

    <input id="file-upload" name="file[]" type="file"/>

    <input id="file-upload" name="video" type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" class="post-button" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

And my php check is like that:

```
$file_field = "images";
    $filenameArr = [];
    if (!empty(array_filter($_FILES[$file_field]['name']))) {
        foreach ($_FILES[$file_field]['name'] as $key => $val) {
            if ($_FILES[$file_field]["error"][$key] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                debugToConsole($_FILES[$file_field]["error"][$key]);
                throw new Exception('There was an error');

            }
        }
    }
```

The error I get is 4 , and I don't understand why ,please help